# How to overcome "Target Display Mode" from preventing sleep after disconnecting?

Tags: terminal, imac, sleep-wake

I use my iMac almost every day as a 27" external display with my MacBook Pro.

- While connected, the iMac won't go to sleep, which is exactly what it is expected.
- But, after disconnecting, the iMac *should* go to sleep. Somehow, it is prevented (in order to always be ready to connect, again?). The problem: If you do not set it to "sleep" manually, it will stay on forever! This is really annoying to find your iMac running all night...

`pmset -g | grep sleep` tells you this:

```bsh
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10 (sleep prevented by sharingd, dpd, useractivityd)
 displaysleep         10 (display sleep prevented by dpd)
```

> Obviously, `sleep` and `display sleep` are prevented by **dpd** ([Display Port Daemon](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/8/dpd/)), see also an unanswered question in *Apple Communities*: [DisplayPort daemon (dpd) blocks sleep even when not in use](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250147170).

Comment: TDM was deprecated 7 years ago. It is full of bugs that will never be fixed. Rather than trying to fix a broken technology into which Apple gives no internal visibility via source code, I would encourage you to consider adopting a more modern and supported workflow instead.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo killall dpd` works quite well! It *seems* like it is not working, because `ps -ax` still lists dpd as a running process. But, when calling *pmset*, the not on "prevented by dpd" is missing:

`pmset -g | grep sleep`

```
hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
networkoversleep     0
disksleep            10
sleep                10 (sleep prevented by sharingd, backupd)
displaysleep         10
```

> **dpd** seems to be **restarted right after killing it**, which does make sense to always allow *Target Display Mode* to be used. But it looks confusing at first.